# how to grab uri values

Tags: php, javascript

i had set a uri like this by java script

```
location.href="biling.php?itemsize="+value5+"&"+value6;
```

and now i want to take this value5 and value6 into php.
think

```
if value5 = 5 and value6=mg
```

then i want to take those values in to php variable 
as 5mg

i tried to do this

```
$sizevalue=preg_replace('\'&\'', '', $_GET['itemsize']);
```

but when i echo it it shows me only "5"
how can i correct this? 
thank you.

Comment: Why do you need this '&'? You put it to the string and then try to remove it. Why don't you just do `location.href="biling.php?itemsize="+value5+value6;`?

Comment: > "biling.php?itemsize="+value5+"&"+value6;

This is not a good usage or GET values.. 
billing.php?itemsize1=value&itemsize2=value2

This will populate $_GET['itemsize1'] and $_GET['itemsize2']. But in your URI, value6 does not populat a key in $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

This script will show you all get Parameters

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
     echo "key:".$key ." Value:".$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this script, maybe.

```
if( $_GET['value5'] == 5 and $_GET['value6']== 'mg' ){
 # do something...
}
```